# Animated gif from base64 datastring and false results

Tags: animation, upload, blob, gif

Hello im uploading from input form a data:image, its works well with png and jpg
but i cant get work it with GIF.

```
  <input value="data:image/gif;base64,...................................." type="hidden" />
```

What i need:

1. Create a file from a string with out losing animation. (the other problem)
2. Copy to a folder

The problem

1. Whatever gif im trying to upload i get a error from if (!$image) that image is not valid. Why ?
2. If i remove $image = @imagecreatefromgif($image); All works but image copied is only first frame from the gif, so its not animated (i heard GD have problems with it, maybe i can just copy full image from datestring, but how to save it right ? )
3. Im tried to use Gifencoder and Gifdecoder and imagemagick but the problem its doesn't recognize a image from datastring , i need to blob it ?

Here is my code

```
function ImageUploadString($data_string) 
{
 $data_string = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $data_string); 
 $data_string = base64_decode($data_string);   // decode image from base64
 $image = imagecreatefromstring($data_string);

 if ($image !== false) {
 $random_imagename = str_shuffle(MD5(microtime()));
 $extention = "gif";
 $ufname = 'folder/'.$random_imagename.'.'.$extention;

$image = @imagecreatefromgif($image); /* Attempt to open */

 if (!$image) {
 imagedestroy($image);
  die('gif error');
   }

 imagegif($image, $ufname);

  }
     }

  $imagebase = "data:image/gif;base64,..........................................";
  ImageUploadString($imagebase);
```